# Need less offensive way to say "he doesn't know the difference between his ass and a hole in the ground."

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, euphemisms, tone

I'm writing something in a tone that is just a little too formal for "he doesn't know the difference between his ass and a hole in the ground" or "he doesn't know dipshit."  I need something that doesn't include words like ass or shit, but that still gets the idea across and packs some punch.  For example, "doesn't know his eye from his elbow" doesn't do it for me.

(This question was already asked within a [different question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/345534/112436), but didn't get any good answers.  I can't place a bounty because the main question was closed.)

Comment: Your "different question" link seems broken. Why did the other answers not suffice? Could you post some of them here?

Comment: @rajah9 - Thank you.  I fixed the link.  "Know the difference between shit and Shinola," "Can't tell your arse from your elbow."  I don't want to use shit or arse in this piece of writing.

Comment: The "punch" comes from the vulgarity. If you want to appear to be scathing then say "he doesn't know the difference between X and Y" and select any term. Go for alliteration, euphemisms  or innuendos.

Comment: Or you could type "doesn't know his" into Google and see what it comes up with. It liked ["head from a hole in the ground"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/know_one%27s_head_from_a_hole_in_the_ground) for me, which I guess is even more insulting than your title example, given the convex nature of heads and the concave nature of holes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I don't have enough imagination to do that well.  Some people do, but not me.

Comment: @Pam - That works for me.  I would give that a check mark.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, a dipshit is a type of person, “jack shit” is what someone doesn’t know.

Comment: Hyperbole can give some punch, but any standup will tell you working blue is the fastest way to get that punch. Something like "He needs a detailed recipe to make ice" could work.

Comment: @jimm101 - I was writing in a fairly formal situation where I just wasn't comfortable with blue.

Comment: A common expression is, "He couldn't find his way out of a paper bag."

Comment: If you are referring to something specific that a person doesn't understand, you can also say, "He wouldn't know an X if he fell over it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a comment, I typed "doesn't know his" into Google to see what it came up with. It liked "head from a hole in the ground".

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/know_one%27s_head_from_a_hole_in_the_ground)

> **know one's head from a hole in the ground**
>
> Synonym of know one's ass from a hole in the ground

Answer (score 2):

**What he doesn't know could fill a book.**

This is an idiomatic way of expressing the breadth and depth of one's ignorance. It should be used to express someone's lack of knowledge in an area that they ought to know something about. If you want to be hyperbolic, replace *book* with *library* for greater effect.

Comment: But this person is stupider than that.  It's not just that there's a ton of stuff she doesn't know.  What she thinks she knows is all wrong, and she has no idea.  Not knowing her head from a hole in the ground -- fits as well as the original without the one troublesome word.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

“He doesn’t know which side of the Earth the Sun comes up on”. That’s what my Grandmother told me.

Answer (score 0):

*He's on a different planet*

*He's a sixpence short of a shilling*

*He's as daft as a brush*

*He's not playing with a full deck (of cards)*

*He's as thick as a plank (of wood)*